# Parse JSON for Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am implemented Spark Structured Streaming, and for my use-case I have to specify the starting offsets.

And, I have the offset values in form of an `Array[String]`:

```
{"topic":"test","partition":0,"starting_offset":123}
{"topic":"test","partition":1,"starting_offset":456}
```

I would like to convert it to the below programmatically, so that I can pass it to Spark.

{"test":{"0":123,"1":456}}

Note: This is just a sample, I keep getting different offset ranges so I cannot hardcode it.

Comment: I guess you are using scala (since you have `Array[String]`)? Have you tried anything? E.g. parsing the JSON to a Map which would be easier to work with as compared to a single string.

Comment: Are you open to dependencies?

Comment: @Shaido , its need be sent it as a json string for the Spark Structured Streaming to start consuming from that offset ranges

Comment: @Angelito Yes, I can work with open source dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is the variable contaning the list you describe then:

```
>>> [{d['topic']: [d['partition'], d['starting_offset']]} for d in array]
[{'test': [0, 123]}, {'test': [1, 456]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> import org.json4s._
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

scala> val topicAsRawStr: Array[String] = Array(
          """{"topic":"test","partition":0,"starting_offset":123}""",
          """{"topic":"test","partition":1,"starting_offset":456}""")

scala> val topicAsJSONs = topicAsRawStr.map(rawText => {
         val json = parse(rawText)
         val topicName = json  \ "topic"  // Extract topic value
         val offsetForTopic = json  \ "starting_offset"  // Extract starting_offset
         topicName -> offsetForTopic
       })
scala> // Aggregate offsets for each topic
```

You can also use spark.sparkContext.parallelize API.

```
scala> case class KafkaTopic(topicName: String, partitionId: Int, starting_offset: Int)

scala> val spark: SparkSession = ???

scala> val topicAsRawStr: Array[String] = Array(
          """{"topic":"test","partition":0,"starting_offset":123}""",
          """{"topic":"test","partition":1,"starting_offset":456}""")

scala> val topicAsJSONs = topicAsRawStr.map(line => json.parse(line).extract[KafkaTopic])

scala> val kafkaTopicDS = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(topicAsJSONs)

scala> val aggregatedOffsetsByTopic = kafkaTopicDS
    .groupByKey("topic")
    .mapGroups {
        case (topicName, kafkaTopics) => 
           val offsets = kafkaTopics.flatMap(kT => kT.starting_offset)
           (topicName -> offsets.toSet)
    }
```

Comment: I had modified my question. There was a typo. Sorry about that.